# C# code to class diagram

Tags: c#, class, uml, diagram, class-diagram

I have a C# solution which has 2 projects in it and I need to generate class diagram from code.

I know there is a built-in diagram tool in visual studio, but I'm using 2010 express and it doesn't have that. Is there any free software that is able to create that? I'm looking only for picture of class hierarchy, nothing more.

Comment: I don't know any free toll, but there are trial version of VS2010: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/try

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try [NClass](http://nclass.sourceforge.net/downloads.html) it's cool in short , I have tried it myself.

**Features:**

- Simple User Interface.
- Free UML class diagram tool specially for C#.
- From diagram to Code generation.
- Classic style class diagrams.
- Visual Studio style class diagrams ;)

[image: Nclass Class Diagram Tool]

> **NOTE:** If you are a student then your school or university can provide you Visual  Studio Professional edition through dreamspark program.

Comment: This doesn't do C#-code TO UML, just the other way around.

Comment: ^^ It does let you import an assembly!

Comment: Just did a C# to UML conversion using NClass 2.04 and it seemed to work OK.  I needed to manually move the shapes around to make it readable.  Might be OK for a simple project but I could see it as being difficult for something more complex.

Comment: I did not understand the question and the answer. The question "C# code to diagram", the answer is "generate C# code by designing class diagram". Why it is the right answer?

Comment: Try this tool [C# UML Diagram Tool](https://www.softwareideas.net/en/csharp-uml-diagram-tool)

Answer (score 5):

This reflexive class diagram creation tool seems useful :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17823/Reflective-Class-Diagram-Creation-Tool

It only needs dll files to works.

Comment: Interesting tool ,it can work with dlls :)